# How to stretch website to resolution screen

Tags: css, html, psd

Im working on website (from psd. to HTML/CSS).

How i can auto match website to resolution of people who watch my website?

PSD template has 1600px width and I set this same width for HTML.

My personal reolution of screen is 1920 x 1080 px, so website for me is not displayed corretly. (browser doesnt stretch website to my resolution)

My HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html"; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>Szablon HTML5</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="slider">
        <div id="stripe">pasek</div>
        <div id="mainpic">obrazek
            <div id="podpis">podpis obrazka</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <div id="boxes">
            <div class="box">
                <h2>Perfect Logic</h2>
                <h3>All you want your website to do.</h3>
                <img src="pictures/minibox.png" class="boxPicture">
                <p>Lore ipsum bla sdk wejhhds asdjh, ajsdhahsd qwjehqwe Lore ipsum bla sdk wejhhds asdjh, ajsdhahsd qwjehqwe Lore ipsum bla sdk wejhhds asdjh, ajsdhahsd qwjehqwe</p>
                <img src="pictures/przycisk.png" class="przycisk">
            </div>
            <div class="box">b</div>
            <div id="box_c">c</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="przerywnik"></div>
    <footer></footer>


</div>

</body>

</html>
```

My CSS file:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ffffff;
  width: 1600px;
  height: auto;
}

#wrapper{
width: 1600px;
height: auto;
}

#header{
height: 137px;
width: 1600px;
background-image:url('pictures/headerbg.png');
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

#logo{
background-image:url('pictures/logo.png');
width: 320px;
height: 137px;
margin-left: 330px;
}

#slider{
height: 426px;
z-index: 2;
}

#stripe{
height: 335px;
background: grey;
z-index: 1;
position: absolute;
background-image:url('pictures/stripe.png');
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

#mainpic{
position: absolute;
z-index: 3;
width: 940px;
height: 343px;
margin-top:22px;
margin-left: 330px;
background-image:url('pictures/slider.jpg');
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
}

#podpis{
margin-top: 338px;
margin-left: 104px;
font-size: 36px;
width: 700px;
position: absolute;
}

/* Część z boxami */

#boxes{
height: 469px;
width: 940px;
margin-left: 330px;
background: #234f31;
}

.box{
float: left;
height: 469px;
width: 320px;
background: #ffffff;
}

.box h2{
font-size: 18px;
margin-top: 21px;
font-family: Georgia;
color: #11719e;
float:left;
}

.box h3{
font-size: 12px;
margin-top: 2px;
font-family: Helvetica;
color: #8c8c8c;
float:left;
}

.box p{
margin-top: 12px;
margin-left: 2px;
font-size: 13px;
color: #3e3e3e;
width: 299px;
float: left;

}

.przycisk{
margin-top: 20px;
margin-left: 2px;
float: left;
width: 163px;
height: 35px;
}

.boxPicture{
margin-top: 15px;
float: left;
height: 198px;
width: 299px;
}

#box_c{
float: left;
height: 469px;
width: 300px;
background: yellow;
}

/* Footer */
#przerywnik{
height: 10px;
width: 1600px;
background: #4c4c4c;
}

footer{
height: 173px;
width: 1600px;
background: #333333;

}
```

How i can fix this?

Comment: You're asking a pretty epic question - you should google 'responsive web design'.

Answer (score 2):

Edit all

```
width:1600px;
```

in your css code to

```
width:100%;
```

Comment: This is a different direction of solution but maybe gives you the desired effect:

keep all the width:1600px; in your design unchanged and add margin: 0px auto; to your #wrapper in the css

Answer (score 0):

Edit this on your code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ffffff;
  width: 1600px;
  height: auto;
}

    #wrapper{
    width: 1600px;
    height: auto;
    }
```

By:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    }
```

---

EDIT:

Here are the code:

```css
    * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#wrapper{
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

#header{
height: 137px;
width: 100%;
background-image:url('pictures/headerbg.png');
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

#logo{
background-image:url('pictures/logo.png');
width: 320px;
height: 137px;
margin-left: 330px;
}

#slider{
height: 426px;
z-index: 2;
}

#stripe{
height: 335px;
background: grey;
z-index: 1;
position: absolute;
background-image:url('pictures/stripe.png');
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

#mainpic{
position: absolute;
z-index: 3;
width: 60%;
  min-width:940px;
height: 343px;
margin-top:22px;
  margin-left:-30%;
  left:50%;
background-image:url('pictures/slider.jpg');
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
}

#podpis{
margin-top: 338px;
margin-left: 104px;
font-size: 36px;
width: 700px;
position: absolute;
}

/* Część z boxami */

#boxes{
height: 469px;
width: 940px;
margin-left: 330px;
background: #234f31;
}

.box{
float: left;
height: 469px;
width: 320px;
background: #ffffff;
}

.box h2{
font-size: 18px;
margin-top: 21px;
font-family: Georgia;
color: #11719e;
float:left;
}

.box h3{
font-size: 12px;
margin-top: 2px;
font-family: Helvetica;
color: #8c8c8c;
float:left;
}

.box p{
margin-top: 12px;
margin-left: 2px;
font-size: 13px;
color: #3e3e3e;
width: 299px;
float: left;

}

.przycisk{
margin-top: 20px;
margin-left: 2px;
float: left;
width: 163px;
height: 35px;
}

.boxPicture{
margin-top: 15px;
float: left;
height: 198px;
width: 299px;
}

#box_c{
float: left;
height: 469px;
width: 300px;
background: yellow;
}

/* Footer */
#przerywnik{
height: 10px;
width: 100%;
background: #4c4c4c;
}

footer{
height: 173px;
width: 100%;
background: #333333;

}
```

Comment: So i supposted to change all values into %?

There are still a lot of divs that are not displayed correctly.

What with height values and rest (font size etc.)?

Comment: For example: #logo, #slider, #mainpic, footer

It didnt moved content of website to center, didnt zoomed the content to look good.

Link to screenshot: http://s11.postimg.org/48e6hglg3/screen3.png

Comment: Well I have make it better. Test it and tell me the new bugs or errors ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think would best be suited to the answer here with a given explanation to your problems: [How to fit your website for all or at lest most screen resolutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19037231/how-to-fit-your-website-for-all-or-at-lest-most-screen-resolutions/19038786#19038786)